# C# Member Variable Scope

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have three/four functions in my VSTO addin and some member variables:

Member Variables:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> clientDict;
private Dictionary<string, string> clientHistoryDict;
```

Function that works with those variables:

```
public void generateClientDict()
{
        clientDict.Add("alcatel-lucent.com", "Alcatel-Lucent");
        clientDict.Add("emerson.com", "Emerson");
        clientDict.Add("ericsson.com", "Ericsson");
        clientDict.Add("fortress-technologies.com", "Fortress Technologies");
        clientDict.Add("genesys.com", "Genesys");
        clientDict.Add("hitachi.com", "Hitachi Data Systems");
        clientDict.Add("hp.com", "Hewlett Packard");
        clientDict.Add("lg.com", "LG Electronics"); 
        clientDict.Add("samsung.com", "Samsung");
        clientDict.Add("sap.com", "SAP");
        clientDict.Add("tellabs.com", "Tellabs");
        clientDict.Add("thiel-audio.com", "Thiel Audio");
        clientDict.Add("xerox.com", "Xerox");
        clientDict.Add("zebra.com", "Zebra Technologies");

        clientHistoryDict.Add("3com.com", "3Com- CommWorks");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("3m.com", "3M");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("abis.com", "ABIS");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("acxiom.com", "Acxiom");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("ajusa.com", "AJ-USA");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("akamai.com", "Akamai Technologies");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("alcatel-lucent.com", "Alcatel-Lucent");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("avaya.com", "Avaya");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("beckmancoulter.com", "Beckman Coulter");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("bellsouth.com", "BellSouth");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("bridgevine.com", "Bridgevine");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("casio.com", "Casio");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("cca.com", "CCA");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("ccs.com", "CCS");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("centurylink.com", "CenturyLink");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("chinatelecom.com", "China Telecom");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("cisco.com", "Cisco");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("comcast.com", "Comcast");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("comodo.com", "Comodo");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("comverge.com", "Comverge");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("coriant.com", "Coriant (Spin off from Tellabs)");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("daneelectric.com", "Dane Electric");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("dell.com", "Dell");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("disney.com", "Disney");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("siemens.com", "Efficient Networks- Siemens");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("emc.com", "EMC");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("emergentcommunications.com", "Emergent Communications");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("emerson.com", "Emerson");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("epson.com", "Epson");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("ericsson.com", "Ericsson");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("exigen.com", "Exigen Services");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("frbny.com", "Federal Reverse Bank of New York");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("hometeamsports.com", "Fox Home Team Sports");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("freemansoundlabs.com", "Freeman Sound Labs");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("genesys.com", "Genesys");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("here.com", "HERE, a Nokia Company");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("hp.com", "Hewlett Packard");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("hitachi.com", "Hitachi Data Systems");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("intel.com", "Intel");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("lg.com", "LG Electronics");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("samsung.com", "Samsung");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("sap.com", "SAP");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("subway.com", "Subway");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("tellabs.com", "Tellabs");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("thiel-audio.com", "Thiel Audio");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("xerox.com", "Xerox");
        clientHistoryDict.Add("zebra.com", "Zebra Technologies");
}
```

Now this function works with the member variables.  (All of these are in the same class).  But these functions do not:

```
public void populateClientDict(SqlConnection conn)
{
        //Dictionary<string, string> clientDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();  If I don't add this I get an error
        try
        {
            using (conn)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                  @"SELECT ClientDirName, ClientEmailDomain FROM ClientTable;",
                  conn);
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string clientDir = reader.GetString(0);
                        string clientEmail = reader.GetString(1);
                        clientDict.Add(clientEmail, clientDir);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No rows found in ClientTable", "Rows Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}

public void populateClientHistoryDict(SqlConnection conn)
{
        //Dictionary<string, string> clientHistoryDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(); if I don't add this I get an error
        try
        {
            using (conn)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                  @"SELECT ClientDirName, ClientEmailDomain FROM ClientHistoryTable;",
                  conn);
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string clientDir = reader.GetString(0);
                        string clientEmail = reader.GetString(1);
                        clientHistoryDict.Add(clientEmail, clientDir);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No rows found in ClientHistoryTable", "Rows Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientHistoryTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientHistoryTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

As I wrote in the commented out line in the functions, unless i declare the dictionaries in those functions I get this error:

I get the error on this line:

`clientDict.Add(clientEmail, clientDir);` in populateClientDict() and `clientHistoryDict.Add(clientEmail, clientDir);` in populateClientHistoryDict()

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Archive.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I  had a feeling the error is related this part of the functions where it says:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
clientDir = reader.GetString(0);
string clientEmail = reader.GetString(1);
clientDict.Add(clientEmail, clientDir);
}
```

ID is the first column, clientDir is the second column, and clientEmail is the third.  Maybe I'm using `reader.GetString()` incorrectly?  I read somewhere I could do something like `reader.GetString["ClientDirName"]` (ClientDirName is the column name) but I'm not sure what the correct thing to do is.

Could this be causing the error?  If so, how can I access the 2nd and 3rd columns (provided ID is the first column) properly to avoid this error.

If not, what else could cause it?

I've tried a ton of combinations, as I said it works if I move the Dictionary instantiations within the functions but I don't think that's solving the actual problem.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: They aren't properties. I have properties and they are public.

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot to `instantiate` your private `clientDict` member `variable` like you do in your `function`.

Comment: Are you sure that calls to both methods are done in the very same instance of the class?

Comment: Are you instantiating the two dictionaries in a constructor? Have you tried using a debugge, setting a breakpoint at the offending lines, and seeing which variables are null?

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown makes sense but then why does the first function work?

Comment: Because you have `instantiated` in your function. It takes the local scope first. If you use `this` in function, than it may not work.

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown if I instantiate them in the functions, can I use them in other functions (all same class)

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown in generateClientDict() I don't instantiate them, just add stuff to them

Comment: No better instantiate them in `constructor`. It might work if you call the `function` that you were `instantiating` the member "first"

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown it's vsto so it's a partial class, not sure where constructor is.  I don't mind instantiating them there, but if I do can I use them in other functions in the same class?\

Comment: or you could just do private Dictionary<string, string> clientDict=new Dictionary<string, string>(); during the declaration itself.

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown I didn't know you could do that cool let me try it.  But if i did instatiate it in a function, would I able to access it from other functions?  Trying to figure out scope in C # a little better.

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown when instantiate the dicts  at declaration at the top, I get the same null reference error.

Comment: If you want to learn more about scope , follow this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown ok it worked instantiating at the declaration, sorry I mistyped something.  Thanks for the link.  Off the top of your head do you know that if a variable created in a class method is accessible from other class methods?   No right?  Because it's in an enclosing scope within the method?  At least that's what I remember from C++

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown if you post an answer summing these comments up I'll accept it.

Comment: No, variable declared inside a `function` is not accessible in other `functions`. It's `local` scope to the containing function only.

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown thought so.  Thanks, like I said compile your comments into an answer and I will accept.  If you want to that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you forgot to `instantiate` the `clientDict` member `variable` like you do in your `function`.

Since your are declaring the same variable in `function` and instantiating, it takes the local scope (when using without `this`) and it works.

You could either instantiate your private member in the `constructor` or during the `declaration` itself.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> clientDict=new Dictionary<string, string>();
private Dictionary<string, string> clientHistoryDict=new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Please follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) link, if you want to know more about scope.